# Disqus and WP not working

Tags: wordpress, disqus

I'm trying to install Disqus on my WP-site and I getting "Unable to connect to the Disqus API servers" and can't install it.

Is there a way to work around this?

I tried to contact their support but I'm getting no answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing a earlier version of the plugin (2.69) before the implemented the auto install function. Filled in all the information manually and then upgraded it to the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that something is blocking the connection between your Wordpress site and Disqus. If someone is hosting your website, you should ask them if they're blocking connections on Port 80, and make sure they can contact 'disqus.com' through that port.

Comment: is there a way to ping servers from within wordpress?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, it would need to be done by a server administrator